# angularjs lookup values from one model into another model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, ng-filter

I am trying to lookup values from one model into another model. How do i achieve this in angular?

Model1: Insurer

[image]

Model2 : currentItems

[image]

I want to filter Insurer model based on values in currentItems model.

Comment: Simple filter+indexOf.

Comment: Could you please give me any example? I am new to angularjs.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Angular, basic javascript array methods. Simply use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with Array.prototype.indexOf or Array.prototype.some for filtering condition.